# Splitting a file with multiline records in R using Regex

Tags: regex, r

I want to parse a 10 GB mbox file and have done so in other languages, but can't seem to figure out how to do it in R.

```
# Message start
From mbox-dev-return-7-apmail-httpd-mbox-dev-archive=httpd.apache.org@httpd.apache.org Thu Sep 20 15:33:02 2001
... # more headers and the body go here
Best, J 
#empty line
#empty line
From mbox-dev-return... # Next message
```

So with regular expression matching a message works with looking for a line starting with From: and then two empty lines. Everything in between is the message.

So far so simple, but I am not really able to apply a Regex in R as I didn't find a method to directly apply it to the file and also not a method to apply it across lines in the read vector.

Here is what I mean in a small example. This version (directly applied to a string) works:

```
> str = "Line one.\nLine two.\nLine three\n\n"
> str_match_all(pattern="(?s)(one.*tw)o", str)
[[1]]
     [,1]             [,2]           
[1,] "one.\nLine two" "one.\nLine tw"
```

But if I first read the file into a Vector, with for example readLines(), then it doesn't work anymore:

```
> str = c("Line one.\n","Line two.\n", "Line three\n\n")
> str_match_all(pattern="(?s)(one.*tw)o", str)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
```

I suspect it broke, because (?s) directive only works across lines in strings, but not across lines in a Vector.

Any idea how to proceed from here?

It doesn't have to be along my small example. Splitting it while reading the file would be fine as well, but I didn't find an R API that does that.

ps. Just in case it is unclear what I am looking for. In Spark I do something like this:

```
inputConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\nFrom ")
val input = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(mailboxFile, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], inputConf)
val mails = input.map { case (_, text) => text.toString }
```

Comment: You can `paste` i.e. `paste(str, collapse='')` and then apply the `str_match_all` to that.

Comment: Thanks, but memory wise I feel that would not be ideal.